# Hide textbox if empty

Tags: javascript, php

I want to make this code hidden if value is `null`,
so if the value is empty, remove this div.

```
div
<?php echo "test" ?>
<input type="text" id="textfield" name"test" value="<?php echo $design_value; ?>"  />
div
```

I can fill value with PHP so when my site load value is null. 
so I need any javascript code that can hide this div if no text on a textbox.

So please try to find any simple code. You can use Javascript or jQuery or whatever you think is better for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use JQuery `$(document).ready`. This event is fired after all elements in the page have initialized and recieved their values:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($("#textfield").val == '')
        $("#textfield").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

get Textbox value , Check if it empty then remove div.

```
var getTextVal= $('#textfield').val();
    if(getTextVal == ""){
      $('#textfield').closest('div').remove();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

if value == '' then hide input field by adding display property to none of that element.
You can do that by running simple javascript code as shown below,

```
    <div id="hide">
    <?php echo "test" ?>
    <input type="text" name="test" id="textfield" value="<?php echo $design_value; ?>"  />
</div>
<script>
    var  hide = document.getElementById("hide");
    var input = document.getElementById("textfield")
        if(input.value == ""){
            hide.style.display = "none";
         }
</script>
```

Comment: its ok but how can i hide  <?php echo "test" ?>
 also

Comment: hey, I got that now you can run that code, It has been edited. Hope that will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by php (it won't show any output):

```
<?php if ($design_value != null) { ?>
<input type="text" id="textfield" name"test" value="<?php echo $design_value; ?>" />
<?php } ?>
```

Or in this way (a hidden field):

```
<input type="<?php echo ($design_value != null) ? 'text' : 'hidden'; ?>" id="textfield" name"test" value="<?php echo $design_value; ?>"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

In plain JavaScript:

```
var textField = document.getElementById('textfield');
var text = textField.value;

textField.parentNode.style.display = (text) ? 'block' : 'none';
```